# Key Commands in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I set key commands like if the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, a new dialog or action happens. And do I have to make a new event for each key command? How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`KeyBinding` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx).

`KeyBinding` allows you to *bind* a keyboard combination to any [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx), including a [`RoutedCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command framework provided for WPF. Some basic commands such as paste, copy, open, etc. are already defined by Microsoft...

You can, however, define new commands. A command can be executed when a button is clicked, a keyboard shortcut is pressed, a menu item is selected, etc.

I am no WPF guru, but my understanding is that using commands is the way to go.

Take a loot at MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx